# crash in Visual Studio when attempting to send an email from Android

Tags: android, email, xamarin, crash

My Xamarin application is crashing when attempting to send an email from Android. Here's my code:

```
public class EmailHelper : Activity, IEmail
{
...
    private bool CreateEmail(string attachment)
    {
        var email = new Intent(Intent.ActionSend);
        SettingsDataAdapter mySettingsDataAdapter = App.MySettingsDataAdapter;
        email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraEmail, new string[] { "test@test.com"});
        email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraSubject, "test email");
        email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraText, "see attachment");
        email.SetType("message/rfc822");
        var file = new Java.IO.File(attachment);
        file.SetReadable(true, false);
        var uri = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(file);
        email.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraStream, uri);
        email.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
        StartActivity(email);
        return true;
    }
...
}
```

and the first error in the output window is:

```
attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.activitythread$applicationthread android.app.activitythread.getapplicationthread()' on a null object reference
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `null object reference`, debug it and determine which object is null........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out after more digging that an Activity cannot be started without a context. I ended up changing

```
StartActivity(email);
```

with

```
((Activity)Forms.Context).StartActivity(email);
```

and that specific error went away.

Just a side note that the next error I hit was "no provider found", which was due to not having an email app configured in the emulator.